# Chrome iframe rendering bug

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have just encountered the strangest bug I have ever seen.

**You can see a demonstration here:** [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txLbn5ot/1/)

I have an iframe from google maps, wrapped in a div that has the following styles:

```
.container {
    width: 600px;
    background: red;

    /* Problematic propeties */
    box-shadow: 0px 40px 20px 0 blue;
    perspective: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* ---- */
}
```

The only style the iframe has, other than default is `display: block`.

The issue is, that the iframe gets moved, depending on the value of box-shadow of its parent div. From my experiments i found out that it gets moved to the right by the: box-shadow blur - box-shadow x-position. Its a little hard to explain so i encourage you to take a look at my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txLbn5ot/1/).

If i remove any of the css propeties that are in the "problematic propeties" comment, the issue goes away. My question is: Is there any way to fix this issue, without removing any of those propeties?

**The issue is only visible in Chrome** - Firefox and IE are fine.

Comment: `perspective: 10px` – what’s that supposed to achieve here? As soon as I remove that, I can toggle the box-shadow on and off, without the iframe moving a bit …

Comment: The perspective is necessary on my full page, as i use css transforms. I removed the transforms for simplicity.